# assigning char array a value in xv6

Tags: c, arrays, call, system, xv6

I made a system call in xv6 and am trying to change the process name. The name of process exists in the proc struct shown below:

```
// Per-process state
struct proc {
  uint sz;                     // Size of process memory (bytes)
  pde_t* pgdir;                // Page table
  char *kstack;                // Bottom of kernel stack for this process
  enum procstate state;        // Process state
  volatile int pid;            // Process ID
  struct proc *parent;         // Parent process
  struct trapframe *tf;        // Trap frame for current syscall
  struct context *context;     // swtch() here to run process
  void *chan;                  // If non-zero, sleeping on chan
  int killed;                  // If non-zero, have been killed
  struct file *ofile[NOFILE];  // Open files
  struct inode *cwd;           // Current directory
  char name[16];               // Process name (debugging)
};
```

I try to access the name with the following code, and assign a value to it:

```
void modifyCurrentProcessName(char* newName)
{
    proc->name= &newName;
}
```

I get the following error:

> proc.c: In function ‘modifyCurrentProcessName’: proc.c:490:15: error:
>   assignment to expression with array type
>        proc->name= &newName;
>                  ^ : recipe for target 'proc.o' failed make: *** [proc.o] Error 1

Comment: `proc->name= &newName;` --> `strcpy(proc->name, newName);`

Comment: You cannot *assign* strings or arrays in C. You must *copy* the string or array to the new location. If it is a *nul-terminated* string, the `strcpy` is fine, if it is simply an array without a terminating *nul-byte*, then `memcpy` or `memmove` must be used.